# Plone Content Type-Specific Portlet Assignment

Tags: python, plone, portlet

I'm developing a content type for Plone 4, and I'd like to block all user, group, and context portlets it may inherit from its parent object. I'm thoroughly confused by the documentation at this point–in portlets.xml, `<blacklist/>` only seems to address path-specific blocking. `<assignment/>` seems like what I want, but it seems too specific–I don't want to manage the assignment for all possible portlets on my content type.

There are hints that I've found that customizing an ILeftColumn and IRightColumn portlet manager specific to the content type, but I can't find any good examples. Does anyone have any hints or suggestions? I feel like I'm missing something dead simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to prevent the portlet aquisition and maintain the possibility of adding portlert you can add an event listener on the creation of your contents that auto blocks the aquisition.

Like this:

```
    <subscriber
        for="my.package.interfaces.IMyContent
             zope.app.container.interfaces.IObjectAddedEvent"                 
handler=".subscribers.blockPortletsUpponMyContentCreation"
                  />
```

and than do this:

```
from zope.component import getMultiAdapter, getUtility
from plone.portlets.interfaces import IPortletManager
from plone.portlets.interfaces import ILocalPortletAssignmentManager
from plone.portlets.constants import USER_CATEGORY
from plone.portlets.constants import GROUP_CATEGORY
from plone.portlets.constants import CONTENT_TYPE_CATEGORY
from plone.portlets.constants import CONTEXT_CATEGORY

def blockPortletsUpponMyContentCreation(mycontent, event):
    for manager_name in ('plone.leftcolumn','plone.rightcolumn'):
        manager = getUtility(IPortletManager, name=manager_name)
        assignable = getMultiAdapter((mycontent, manager,), ILocalPortletAssignmentManager)
        for category in (GROUP_CATEGORY, CONTENT_TYPE_CATEGORY,CONTEXT_CATEGORY,USER_CATEGORY):
            assignable.setBlacklistStatus(category, 1)
```

Note: this code is inspired by the [plone.app.portlet manage view](http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/plone.app.portlets/trunk/plone/app/portlets/browser/manage.py)

Edit 19/08/2011: included fixes as suggested by @will in my untested code...so now is tested

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted to do, it blocks existing portlets while retaining the user's ability to assign them in future. I was so caught up trying to do something in portlets.xml that a subscriber hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: For posterity, there are a couple of modifications that should be made to the above code, to make it work. In the ZCML, the `factory` attribute should be `handler`, the manager names need to be matched to their respective `IPortletManager` managers with `getUtility()`.

Comment: @Will please could you mark this answer as the answer of your question ?

Comment: In my addon I had to check the getMultiAdapter call for zope.component.interfaces.ComponentLookupError exceptions. Otherwise copying / pasting an object through the ZMI wouldn't work.

Maybe it would be safe to do the same in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Do the assignment to your portaltype live on a site via Sitesetup (controlpanel) -> Types -> "Manage portlets assigned to this content type".

Then export the configuration via ZMI -> portal_setup -> Export-Tab -> select 'Portlets' -> click 'export' on bottom.

Extract the types/YourType.xml-file and copy the relevant parts in your package's profiles/default/types/YourType.xml.

Comment: it seems the this way you can only add portlets, not block the parents portlet. Are you sure of that way?

Comment: Ah no, it's not possible to block that way, I was only referring to your second paragraph. You don't want to block prtlets entirely, but still be able to assign new ones, do you?