# Plone 4 Navigation Portlet, show only in non-folderish children

Tags: plone

Starter Info: Working with Plone 4.0.7 on CentOS 5.5 with Python 2.6.6.

I've got a folder that contains a few pages and I want to have a navigation portlet on all of the child pages but not the parent folder. My first thought of how to do this was to add the navigation portlet to the parent folder, pointing to itself, and setting the start level to 1. This works for not showing the portlet on the parent, but none of the child Pages are showing the portlet. I assume this is because the Pages aren't a folderish content type so the start level doesn't apply to them. Does anyone know where I would start to look to create a work around for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm the issue.
The problem seems to be, that pages/documents are not recognized as subsections but as an item of the containing folder. 
You can counterproof that, if you add folders to your folder, with them the navigation will work as you expect.
As a workaround you could use CSS to hide the navi on the folder with sth like:
.portaltype-folder .portletNavigation { display: none; }

Answer (score 0):

Actually your method *is* the right method:

1. add the navigation portlet in the parent folder
2. set the initial level to 1. If child pages don't diplay the portlet check if they block the parent portlet acquisition.
3. go to every child folder and block the portlet acquisition. If the number of child folder is hight, you can [programmatically block the acquisition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432317/plone-content-type-specific-portlet-assignment/7435909#7435909)

Comment: there are no child folders. Out of the box if you create a folder with 3 pages in it and create a navigation portlet in the folder and set the settings as above you will not be able to see the nav portlet although it isn't blocked

Comment: the behaviour is as i said, I've tested it. You're probably making some mistake. Are you sure that you have defined the portlet in the direct parent folder and not in a content selected as the folder's default view?

Comment: You tell me if I'm making a mistake http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ar4TW2XIk6Q. The audio got way out of sync when I uploaded it to YouTube, sorry about that

Comment: Yes, you are doing it right. I did another test and the behaviour is as you said. I don't remember how I did my first test, maybe I was wrong. The trick in the @Ida 's answer  seems to be one of the easiest ways to solve your problem.

Comment: I can confirm this issue. I am having the same problem. Does anyone know if this can be fixed?